# Why does an executable jar with derby not work?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, derby

I am developing a simple app as a school project that is designed to be used by the client on his computer. I decide to use derby DB as it can work in embedded mode. However as everything works fine in eclipse, when I try to export it to executable jar file the app does not work properly.

I am trying to connect to DB and create tables if they don't exist as shown in the code. After the first launch of a jar new file named sampleDB appears on a screen so I guess that db is created. However, besides GUI components, the program does not work at all. I am executing those table methods in main as the first ones so I guess there may be something wrong with them, however, eclipse doesn't show any errors.

Here is a fragment of code responsible for connection and the creation of a table, that I mentioned.

```
        public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{
            try {    
                Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
                  //Getting the Connection object
                  String URL = "jdbc:derby:sampleDB;create=true";
                  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
                return conn;    
            }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
            return null;
    }
        public static void table1() throws Exception {
             Connection conn = getConnection();
             try {
              java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
              if  (!doesTableExists("costs", conn)) {
             String query= "CREATE TABLE costs("
                     +"Id INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, "
                     +"Name VARCHAR(60),"
                     +"value DOUBLE NOT NULL, "
                     +"driverdependent INT NOT NULL,"
                     +"costorpofit INT NOT NULL, "
                     +"fixedorvariable INT NOT NULL,"
                     +"driver VARCHAR(40),"
                     +"truck VARCHAR(40),"
                     +"semitrailer VARCHAR(40),"
                     +"Data TIMESTAMP,"
                     +"PRIMARY KEY (Id))";
             stmt.execute(query);
              }
        }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
        }
        static boolean doesTableExists(String tableName, Connection conn)
                throws SQLException {
            DatabaseMetaData meta = conn.getMetaData();
            ResultSet result = meta.getTables(null, null, tableName.toUpperCase(), null);
            return result.next();
        }
        public static void table2() throws Exception {
            try {
         Connection conn = getConnection();
         java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        if  (!doesTableExists("journeys", conn)) {
            String query= "CREATE TABLE journeys("
                 +"Id INT NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY, "
                 +"millage DOUBLE NOT NULL, "
                 +"driver VARCHAR(40),"
                 +"truck VARCHAR(40),"
                 +"semitrailer VARCHAR(40),"
                 +"Data TIMESTAMP,"
                 +"PRIMARY KEY (Id))";
        stmt.execute(query);
        }
        }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
    }
        public static void table3() throws Exception {
            try {
             Connection conn = getConnection();
             java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
             if  (!doesTableExists("routes", conn)) {
             String query= "CREATE TABLE routes("
                     +"millage DOUBLE NOT NULL, "
                     +"Name VARCHAR(40))";
                stmt.execute(query);
             }
            }catch(Exception e) {System.out.println(e);}
            }
```

Comment: what error are you facing , try to minimize your problem

Comment: So as Andrew Thompson pointed out I am currently operating in an embedded mode which is read-only. What should I do in order to make this application applicable to my task. (client have the app on his computer where he can both update and read the database)

Comment: Include the *actual* error you are getting, don't just say "the app does not work properly." I don't think the answers you have been given so far are correct. You need to provide more details in order to get to the root of your problem.